# How to return the frequency of each value for every item inside of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a very large pandas dataframe like this:

```
id   fruit
---|------
101  apple
102  apple
101  watermelon
101  orange
102  orange
104  lemon
105  lemon
104  lemon
105  apple
103  grapes
```

How can I create a count dataframe, where each id is representing the frequency of fruits across the columns, something like this:

```
     apple   watermelon  orange  lemon  grapes

101    1         1         1       0      0
102    2         0         1       0      0
103    0         0         0       0      1
104    0         0         0       0      2
105    1         0         0       0      0
```

I tried to:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['id','fruit']).count()
new_df
```

And

```
new_df = df[['id','fruit']].groupby(['id','fruit']).count()
new_df
```

And

```
new_df = df[['id','fruit']].groupby(df['fruit'].tolist()).count()
new_df
```

However, I am not getting the expected output. Any idea of how to create the desired output from the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use: [.crosstab()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
pd.crosstab(df.id,df.fruit)
Out[251]: 
fruit  apple  grapes  lemon  orange  watermelon
id                                             
101        1       0      0       1           1
102        1       0      0       1           0
103        0       1      0       0           0
104        0       0      2       0           0
105        1       0      1       0           0
```

Comment: @tumbleweed you can check the link man : -) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.crosstab.html

Comment: Just one thing Wen, when I try to save the dataframe as a .csv file I lose the id column, how can I split the blank space between the fruit and preserving the id?

Comment: @tumbleweed I think you can add reset_index() at the end